# Throughput Shaping Timer, TPS distribution inside the scenario

Tags: jmeter

I have a question that has to do with the Throughput Shaping Timer usage. Maybe I have to use another plugin to cover my demand, but anyway I decided at least to investigate it and understand the behavior.

**The task - emulate 20 TPS on the platform for the following user scenario:**

[image: The test plan]

But with the strict TPS distribution:

1. Login - 1 TPS
2. Get user info - 6 TPS
3. Search - 12
4. Logout - 1 TPS

**Throughput Shaping Timer investigation**

I made the following:

1. Added the "Concurrency thread group" with flexible settings, just to be lazy and delegate the threads set up to the plugin.
   [image]
2. Added the "Throughput shaping timer"
   [image]

**Results/questios**:

- I got 4.8 TPS on average for all requests (I suppose it's expected for the current flow)
  [image]
- General TPS time to time is more than 20 TPS set in the test. Is it OK, or some settings are incorrect? from my understanding the peaks are too high..
  [image]
- Some requests have TPS peaks, looks not very good due to peaks
  [image]

So the questions:

1. Is it possible to apply some tunings (or set/change flow) for the current stack of the tools ("Concurrency thread group" with flexible settings and "Throughput shaping timer") to distribute target 20 TPS like described in the task?
2. How "Throughput shaping timer" divide the TPS between threads?
3. Please suggest the best solution for the current task

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different throughputs is not something you can achieve within the bounds of a single Thread Group because according to JMeter threads model JMeter waits for the previous response before starting the next request therefore all your scenarios will act at the speed of the slowest one.

So you need to split your requests and put each one under the separate Thread Group and apply the throughput shaping individually.

If you need to pass some data like cookies or tokens from the "Login" sampler to other thread groups you either need to convert them into JMeter Properties using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) in the "Login" thread group and [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in other thread groups or go for [Inter-Thread Comminucation Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter/)

Comment: Many thanks for the suggested solution, so now would be a challenge to achieve a new plugin. One user logged in I need to share the auth token and all thing to have an active session in another thread group. @Dmitri T do we have some articles, examples of how to pass cookies with tokens to other thread groups? The mechanism is clear from the link you posted, I'm worrying that something else should be considered as well for such sharing, definitely I will try to achieve :)